# Targeting Android 12+, android:exported problem

Tags: javascript, android

Today i decided to target my applications to Android 12+, setted all "android exported" but got the issue in one signal.

Have you guys any idea to define it in manifest? I tryed few ways but the only working way was update onesignal to version 4+, currently i am using 3.11.4.

Sadly in this fix method my 2 classes has been ruined because in 4+ version NotificationExtenderService and OSNotificationReceivedResult not longer exist, i am right?

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ukd.png)

Here s my manifest.

```
package="com.makeMoney.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.Settings" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.Detail_Activity" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.About" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.MainActivity" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.Splash" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.TheJobChromium"
        android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/transparent"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <service
        android:name="com.makeMoney.myapplication.Activity.OutsideNotification"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: @KaoLai232 did you find a solution you can share ?